# Querying content of Windows Media Center library

Tags: c#, windows-media-center

I'm trying to create a program in C# that lists the content of a library in Windows Media Center (for instance the video library).

Is this possible using the Windows Media Center SDK, without having to create it as an addin for WMC, but as an "external" program, running on the same machine as WMC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't look to good, quote from MSDN:

*With a few exceptions, the Windows Media Center object model is not accessible from a Windows service or any other process other than those started by Windows Media Center.*

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms816271.aspx

Though I don't know what those exceptions are.

Comment: That might explain why I can't get it to work :) - Thanks for the answer